# LocallAPStore IAP cracker - how to protect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have a verification server set up that receives purchase receipts from our iOS app over SSL.  The receipts are then validated against the iTunes Connect server successfully and all works well.  However, if we jailbreak the iOS device and install LocalIAPStore via Cydia, the device can purchase anything without the user being charged.  The receipts are still sent to our server and successfully validated, but the user on the device is never charged and no real transaction ever occurs.  How could it be that Apple servers successfully verify the receipt?!?

Has anyone ran into this scenario with LocalIAPStore?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "The receipts are still sent to our server and successfully validated".  I suspect that you are being handed the same old receipt over and over again.  Your server can log the transaction_id in the receipt and refuse to validate any duplicate transaction_id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try out even tho this will not prevent them from using it.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/LocalIAPStore.dylib"]) {
    NSLog(@"Local IAP Store detected");
}
```

This in not very effective, but it might stop someone from doing it. You may want to make your own server (server-sided app) for the app to make it impossible for them to use LocalIAPStore and such.